# Operation on copied list2 (list2 = list1.copy()) or sliced list (list2 = list1[:]) are altering the content of source list1

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of dictionaries - list1.

I want to copy the content of list1 into content of another list (list2) so that list1 and list2 are pointing to different objects in memory.

Per my understanding this should be possible using any of the following list2 assignment:

1. list2 = list1.copy()
2. list2 = list1[:]

However, after assigning list2 with any of above method, when I change the content of list2 in for loop, i see the content of source list (list1) is also changed.

Could you help to explain why this happens? And how to overcome this problem?

Thanks!
BR,
Bartek

Test Code - Tested on Python 3.11.2 and on old Python 3.6.8:

```
list1 = [
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}
]
list2 = list1.copy()
# list2 = list1[:]

print("Source list1: ", list1)
print("Copied list2: ", list2)
print()

for item in list2:
    for key in item:
        item[key] += 1

print("Source list1: ", list1)  # I expect the content should not be altered, since in for loop i operate on list2
print("Copied list2: ", list2)  # I expect the content should be altered
```

Test Code result -> List1 content is also altered:

```
Source list1:  [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}]
Copied list2:  [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}]

Source list1:  [{'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 4}, {'a': 5, 'b': 6, 'c': 7}]
Copied list2:  [{'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 4}, {'a': 5, 'b': 6, 'c': 7}]

Process finished with exit code 0
```